# Controlling python GUI using erlang

Tags: python, erlang, protocols, wxwidgets, erlang-ports

I am new to python and I'm trying to use python to build a GUI.

I am using wxGlade to generate a GUI code and erlport to connect it to Erlang.

My problem is that I don't know how to work both the GUI and the erlport together with their classes. After starting the GUI I want to control the display with Erlang messages.

This is the GUI code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
#
# generated by wxGlade 0.8.3 on Wed Aug  8 22:17:32 2018
#

import wx

# begin wxGlade: dependencies
# end wxGlade

# begin wxGlade: extracode
# end wxGlade


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__init__
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((150, 80))
        self.text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "", style=wx.TE_CENTRE | wx.TE_READONLY)

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.edit_text, self.text_ctrl)
        # end wxGlade

    def __set_properties(self):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__set_properties
        self.SetTitle("frame")
        # end wxGlade

    def __do_layout(self):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__do_layout
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_1.Add(self.text_ctrl, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        self.Layout()
        # end wxGlade

    def edit_text(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
        print("Event handler 'edit_text' not implemented!")
        event.Skip()

# end of class MyFrame

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

# end of class MyApp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

And this is example code using erlport

```
from erlport import Port, Protocol

class HelloProtocol(Protocol):

    def handle_hello(self, name):
        return "Hello, %s" % name

if __name__ == "__main__":
    proto = HelloProtocol()
    proto.run(Port(use_stdio=True))
```

I would like to know how I can combine both so I would be able to run the GUI and edit the texts for example using messages from erlang

Comment: Why are you not want to use wxErlang?

Comment: Because there are GUI builders for wxPython which make the designing much easier and its by doing that I'll get extra points for the project

Comment: Good point, unfortunately, there is not form builders for wxErlang. But it still could be better rewrite GUI with wxErlang than use port, especially if GUI isn't big.